# How I make a Blacklist with JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want make a blacklist with a JSON file. I want put the id in JSON file and when the member join a guild with the bot, the member is banned.

My code :

```
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    let blacklist = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./blacklist.json", "utf8"));
        bot.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
          if (!blacklist[member.id]) return
          if(blacklist[member.id].state === true) {
            member.ban()
          }
        })
    })
```

Json File

```
{
    "id":"664514598086508605"
}
```

Comment: You have not provided a problem statement regarding the objective you have stated and the code that is shown. What is or isn't working  and what errors are you encountering (if any)?

Comment: I havn't error code and I try the code up.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `.includes()` method but it will require some changes to your json file so that it is like this

```
{
  "123456789123456789",
  "987654321987654321"
}
```

then your code will become

```js
const blacklist = require('blacklisted.json')

// ...

bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  if (blacklisted.includes(member.id)) {
    member.{ reason: 'Automatic ban, blacklisted user' }
  }
})
```

this code will automatically ban anyone who is blacklisted from joining a server that the bot is in

using your original code

```js
const blacklist = require('blacklisted.json')

// ...

bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  bot.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
    if (blacklisted.includes(member.id)) {
      member.{ reason: 'Automatic ban, blacklisted user' }
    }
  });
});
```

This will ban the user from all servers when the user joins one of them